# getting Video URL using Python Scripting

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am working with beautiful soup to extract the URL. I get all the attributes of the href but i want to get only specific URL.
Here is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
page=requests.get("https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=cooking")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content ,'html.parser')
for a_tag in soup.findAll("a"):
    if a_tag.has_attr("href"):
            print(a_tag['href'])
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VrwGk.png)
 but i want only this 
watch?v=nTe_44ao82w
/watch?v=nTe_44ao82w

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More Minimization to the first answer:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
page=requests.get("https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=cooking")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content ,'html.parser')
for a_tag in soup.findAll("a"):
    if 'watch' in a_tag['href']:
            print(a_tag['href'])
```

This will check if the `href` tag has string `watch` in it. 
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't really seem to be a good way to differentiate those a tags other than by the URL itself (they don't have any unique classes or anything) so I would probably just check if the URL contains "watch":

```
...
for a_tag in soup.findAll("a"):
    if a_tag.has_attr("href") and "watch" in a_tag["href"]:
            print(a_tag['href'])
```

Outputs

```
/watch?v=cbxe1ANrfDo
/watch?v=nTe_44ao82w
/watch?v=v1wIThmCams
/watch?v=FTociictyyE
/watch?v=dw2QHkAtB_Y
/watch?v=ej9UHVwlQqk
/watch?v=KGAj8IhnR3c
/watch?v=G8A73R_gZdM
/watch?v=XPQW_2YOmjY
/watch?v=J0pS2lhH0Vc
/watch?v=5aU5qrbCsF4
/watch?v=kvAJ_mc9NXs
/watch?v=kKiYVLIk_9s
/watch?v=G2jYIGdmC6I
/watch?v=jMW5ZDQviOA
/watch?v=iTmcGy9CWhE
/watch?v=66Ck_5SePZg
/watch?v=lyD9t3uhHio
```